# Bash script and alias

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to run this script

```
#!/bin/bash
# alias.sh

shopt -s expand_aliases
# Must set this option, else script will not expand aliases.


# First, some fun.
alias Jesse_James='echo "\"Alias Jesse James\" was a 1959 comedy starring Bob Hope."'

echo;
echo
```

As output I got two empty lines only.Why?

Do I need to export alias.sh into .bashrc?If yes,why?

I got the code from

http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/aliases.html

Comment: You didn't make a call to `Jesse_James`

Comment: What do you expect the output to be?  You define an alias called `Jesse_James`, but never call it.

Comment: @anubhava How to make a call,can you make example pleaes?

Comment: BTW, you might consider finding a better reference than the ABS -- one of the common chores in the freenode bash channel is helping people unlearn bad habits they picked up there.

Comment: Also, why are you bothering to use an alias *at all*? Shell functions work in scripts by default out-of-the-box, without any need to play around with non-portable commands like `shopt`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I will need to change directory in my code,so I thought it would be good to learn how alias works.

Comment: You can change directory in a function

Comment: `mycd() { cd /to/somewhere; }`. And, unlike in an alias, you can do conditional logic in a function based on parameters passed: `mycd() { if (( $# )); then cd "$HOME/foo.d/$1"; else cd "$HOME/bar"; fi; }`

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks,will try for sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The complete example is:

```
#!/bin/bash
# alias.sh

shopt -s expand_aliases
# Must set this option, else script will not expand aliases.


# First, some fun.
alias Jesse_James='echo "\"Alias Jesse James\" was a 1959 comedy starring Bob Hope."'
Jesse_James
```

In this case, the alias `Jesse_James` gets called on the last line.  In your question, this line is missing and thus the alias never gets called.